# Error in sentence splitting from documents using spacy sentencizer

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, sentence

I am using the sentencizer from spacy to split the document into sentences. The default delimiters in sentencizer is (' . ' , ' ! ' , ' ? ' ). But if i gave a sentence like:

"A fawn was racing in the forest!He was ahead of the rabbit?He was ahead of the elephant."

Its not splitting into 3 sentences.

I tried this :

```
sen = "A fawn was racing in the forest!He was ahead of the rabbit?He       
was ahead of the elephant." 
nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'), first=True)
doc = nlp(sen)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

But it's not splitting in the !, ?.

The expected output for the input:

"A fawn was racing in the forest!He was ahead of the rabbit?He was ahead of the elephant."

```
"A fawn was racing in the forest!"

"He was ahead of the rabbit?"

"He was ahead of the elephant."
```

Can anyone help for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with sentences missing space after the period when preceded by a quote, like:

> He told me "Go somewhere else".But I didn't want to go.

The solution is in this document: [Customizing spaCy’s Tokenizer class](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers)

I got further inspiration from [Adding Custom Tokenization Rules to spaCy](http://www.longest.io/2018/01/27/spacy-custom-tokenization.html)

Here is a rule that works - basically copied from [Adding Custom Tokenization Rules to spaCy](http://www.longest.io/2018/01/27/spacy-custom-tokenization.html):

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):

    prefixes_re = spacy.util.compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)

    custom_infixes = ['\.\.\.+', '(?<=[0-9])-(?=[0-9])', '[?!&:,()]']
    infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(tuple(list(nlp.Defaults.infixes) + custom_infixes))

    suffix_re = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)   

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions,
                     prefix_search = prefixes_re.search, 
                     infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer, suffix_search = suffix_re.search,
                     token_match=None)


nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
```